# QEMUI/KVM virtio-serial does not have host to VM connectivity

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, tty, libvirt

I added a virtual serial in my xml to enable host -> vm and vm -> host connections over serial.

```
echo "a string" #on VM
```

then

```
cat < {pts-path} #on Host
```

Works as expected, I am able to see the string that is echoed fro the VM.
However, the inverse e.g echoing from the host, then doing a cat on the serial to see the data doesn't return anything.

the entry in my xml is

```
<channel type="pty">
  <source path="/dev/pts/{}"/>
  <target type="virtio" name="org.fedoraproject.port.1" state="disconnected"/>
  <alias name="channel0"/>
  <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
</channel>
```

Not sure why state is 'disconnected' I don't seem to be able to set it to connected.